# Sometimes the SESSION loads, sometimes not

Tags: php, session, session-state

I request your help - I don't have any ideas left...

My script performs following steps:

1. login.php -> Authenticate the user. If positive the session is set with user-data (user-id, roles, ...), if not the session wil be destroyed.
2. When positive, index.php is called by redirect.
3. index.php includes the file noypum.php
4. noypum.php shows/logs the session.

**Problem:** Sometimes it works fine at the first time: login and noypum has the session-data. But sometimes the login.php sets the session correctly but noypum.php and index.php has an active session but an empty session-array. Then you login a second time an it works.

I don't get any errors from php or in the F12-console. Also the files were all found (200) - only the favicon has still a 404...

**login.php**

```
if(isset($user['password']) && isset($_POST['pw'])){
   if(password_verify ( $_POST['pw'].$pepper , $user['password'] )){
      $_SESSION['usercount'] = $usercount['usercount'];
      $_SESSION['uid'] = $user['id'];
      $_SESSION['uroles'] = $user['roles'];
      $_SESSION['SESS_created'] = time();
      $_SESSION['ID_created'] = time();
      $data = $conf->load("divers");
      $startseite = $data['startseite'];
      $args = array();
      $args[] = $user['id'];
      $dbm->query("update y_user set lastlogin=NOW() where id=?",$args, false);
      $log->success(21091201, "Login OK");
      $conf->redirect($startseite);
      exit();
}}
```

**index.php** (from the top)

```
<?php require_once("./ypum/yback/noypum.php"); 
// Logger (into Statistiker-Datenbank)
@require_once(__DIR__."/u_include/inc.php");
$log = new logger($db_stat, 0);
if(!isset($_SESSION['uroles'])) $log->error(21091192, "NO ROLES SET IN index.php");
else $log->success(21091106, "Roles aus Session (index.php): ".$_SESSION['uroles']);

$version = '1.0.7';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
```

**noypum.php** (from the top)

```
<?php 
namespace ypum;
session_start(); 
require_once(__DIR__."/../../u_include/classes/logger.php");
$log = new \logger();

$log->debug(21091299, var_export($_SESSION, true));
$log->debug(21091203, "Session status: ".session_status());
```

Output:

- array ()
- Session status: 2 *(2 = PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE, if sessions are enabled, and one
  exists.)*

Why ist the SESSION-Array sometimes empty? Why does it work sometimes at the first attempt?

**Thank you very much for your help!**

UPDATE 1: If the error occurs, noypum.php starts a brandnew session with a new SESSION-ID (expected, but now confirmed).

UPDATE 2:
The beginning of **login.php** after the comment from Ali Akbar Azizi
(thx):

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION = array();

session_destroy();
ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 1);
session_start();
var_dump (session_status());

require_once(__DIR__."/../yback/include/inc_main.php");
require_once(__DIR__."./../../u_include/classes/logger.php");
$log = new logger();
$log->debug(21091212, "Login-Session-Init, Session-Status: ".session_status());
...
...
```

Comment: can you check result of session_status in first time in login.php before redirect? ( by the first time i mean when the session is empty )

Comment: Right after session_start the session has the status PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE

Comment: Can you try it before redirect? also try to move these 4 line in `if(isset($user['password'])` , maybe its because of them `session_destroy();
ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 1);
session_start();
var_dump (session_status());
`

Comment: Before redirect it is also "2" and I readout the session_id at that point.
The other suggestion from you I will check after dinner ;)  Thank you

Comment: Putting the 4 lines into `if(isset($user['password'])` makes the login to fail all the time...

Comment: just remove this line, this line has issue, you destroy session on every page load, this is not good practice, imagine if you have a bug that make a request to login ( or other page that redirect to login ) that make all session destroy. in general you dont need to destroy session but if you want you have to put it on if statement somehow

Comment: I deleted the destroy and just empty the array, bit it makes no change. I'm not quite sure if I understood your points. After the redirect there is no fall-back to the login.php. Errors I also don't realize. I have to prevent that a new user can't get session-fragments from the user before even if he didn't log out. But the biggest point: it is still not working :(

Comment: still you should not empty session array. just imagine if user open login page it work like logout, so technically you need to add if to check user is logged in or not. then redirect if user is logged in also it make CSRF issue. for your code, it obviuse some where in your code you make session array empty, so for that the easy way to find it is add `$_SESSION['pagename'] = 1` in every page and see whats going on

Comment: Thank you. I deleted all that stuff and unfortunatley that was not the point...